# Yarn monorepo & typescript paths in packages

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, monorepo

Has anyway succeeded in making this work? We have a yarn workspace, consisting of packages and apps. E.g.:

```
libs
  ui
    src
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
apps
  app-1
    src
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
```

`app-1` is configured to resolve `libs/ui` as `@org/ui` and imports do work.

What I want to be able to do is use absolute imports in the UI package, so for example I will have imports like `@/components/link` instead of `../../../link` when the structure is a bit more complex.

I know that this is possible if I compile UI separately, but I am trying to get away from this as I want to have the `app-1` do all the compilation. I could also use the `@org/ui` path in the ui package as well, but it kinda feels weird. I would like to be able to use `@/` in both the UI and the app package.

Has anyone been able to make this work? Is there some TS plugin that can fix the paths under the hood?

Comment: have you ever figured this out? Is there a solution to having `app-1` do all the compilation and honor the paths in sub modules?

Comment: Unfortunately not for now. I guess the only option is to have lib-level compilation, but this comes with it's own considerations

Comment: so i've had some luck with writing a resolver plugin. I check to see who is the initiatior, and then validate the path. Pretty crude, i just hardcoded my things like `~/*` , `src` , `packages` . So it's not universal, but is now compiling across packages without me having to build, and each package resolves it's own absolute paths with `~/`